# react native location permission is already granted

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

Im using react native cli, and using background geolocation. (currently I'm using for android only)
I tried to publish the app to play store but they say I must add a permission to use location service.

I did some search for it, but it didnt work out for me:

I tried:

```
async  requestLocationPermission(){
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Example App',
          'message': 'Example App access to your location '
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the location")
        alert("You can use the location");
      } else {
        console.log("location permission denied")
        alert("Location permission denied");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }
  

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.requestLocationPermission()
```

but it goes directly to granted..: "You can use the location".

Before I moved to background geolocation it did ask for permission but now I didnt even notice for that untill got rejected by google play.

I made some research for that but couldnt get it work.

sorry for my english and I really appreciate if you could help me with that.
I need that location permission dialog.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    
     <!-- <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/> -->
      </activity>
        <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="..."/>
    </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Whichever permissions you ask of the user, they have to be added to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#foreground)

Comment: thanks for you answer, I already have that on manifest